# Declaring a toast within a Handler message

Tags: android, toast

Is it possible to call a Toast from within a handler?  If so, how?  My current code is generating a NullPointer Exception.

Here is my code:

```
Handler messageHandler = new Handler() {

    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"THIS IS TOAST DIALOG",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
        prgBar.setVisibility(prgBar.INVISIBLE);
       }
};
```

MY LOG REPORT:

```
09-13 18:18:51.493: E/AndroidRuntime(1727): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

09-13 18:18:51.493: E/AndroidRuntime(1727): java.lang.NullPointerException

09-13 18:18:51.493: E/AndroidRuntime(1727): at    android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:100)

09-13 18:18:51.493: E/AndroidRuntime(1727): at com.example.threadingexperiment.ThreadingExperiment$1.handleMessage(ThreadingExperiment.java:46)
```

SHOWING ERROR AT LINE:

```
Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"THIS IS TOAST DIALOG",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
```

Comment: where you initialized prgBar.

Comment: at which line you got an exception ?

Comment: Show the error log of the nullpointer please.

Comment: ProgressBar-prgBar  is not important in this issue. even if I comment out the prgBar I still have this error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't reach the ApplicationContext from your Handler.

You should use the Context from the Activity this handler is in.

Comment: I replaced my code with this:                                                  Toast toast=Toast.makeText(ThreadingExperiment.this,"THIS IS TOAST DIALOG",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);         --still having an error

Comment: ThreadingExperiment is basically my Main Activity. This class calls another thread class which performs a lengthy action.On completion of this action, messageHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0); is called. Got it??

Comment: So ThreadingExperiment extends from Activity? If it does I wouldn't know what's going wrong.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5462576/passing-context-to-handler

Maybe this is usefull