# How to extend Handler in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

There is a popular java pattern to extend a `Handler` and store a weak reference to the context, to prevent memory issues, etc. For example, this pattern can be found in the top answer in [Passing context to Handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5462576/passing-context-to-handler)

In my case, my code before the `handleMessage` function is:

```
public class MessageHandler extends Handler {

    WeakReference<Context> contextReference;

    public MessageHandler(Context context) {
        contextReference = new WeakReference<>(context);
    }
```

Recently, I have needed to do the same in Kotlin, and I am unable to do it without errors. Android Studio's java-to-kotlin translation doesn't complete do it, and I tried to edit, and still get errors. Could somebody point out where I am doing it wrong? I am combining class extension, constructor, `init` function, and don't know know where I messed up? Why does it not recognise `context` despite my having the import statement?
[image: Android Studio shows various errors]

Sorry I can't figure it out as I am not a kotlin developer, would appreciate any help anyone could give, thanks.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted source code as text instead of, or in addition to, images.

Comment: Can you add the compiler error to the question? It's much easier to suggest a solution when it's clear what the actual error is.

Comment: See [Inheritance | Kotlin Documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inheritance.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This way you can use Kotlin.

```
class MessageHandler(context: Context) : Handler() {

    var contextReference: WeakReference<Context> = WeakReference<Context>(context)

    override fun publish(p0: LogRecord?) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun flush() {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun close() {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
}
```